# Missing class files when compiling set of Java files using javac

Tags: java, cmd, compilation, javac

I am compiling a set of Java files using **javac**. With following command I save all Java files into a text file:

```
dir *.java /S /B > files.txt
```

Here a short extract of **files.txt**:

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\source\org\apache\commons\lang3\AnnotationUtils.java
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\source\org\apache\commons\lang3\ArchUtils.java
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\source\org\apache\commons\lang3\ArrayUtils.java
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\source\org\apache\commons\lang3\BitField.java
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\source\org\apache\commons\lang3\BooleanUtils.java
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\source\org\apache\commons\lang3\CharEncoding.java
>   ...

Now that I have all my sources in one file I want to compile them with following command:

```
javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 -g -cp @files.txt
```

with the output...

> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

When I now switch to the sources folder I can see some of the compiled files but not all. For example the file `AnnotationUtils.class` is missing.

I am expecting to see for each Java file a class file plus class files for inner classes or at least an error message during compilation.

What causes this and how can I solve it?

---

- I am using the sources of [org.apache.commons.lang3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.9)
- I tried compiling with:

  - OpenJDK 11
  - JDK 11
  - JDK 8

Comment: Why are you trying to compile a maven project with a manually constructed build batch script, instead of using maven?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Basically I am trying to compile source code with different JDK's and compiler options so that I can compare the resulting bytecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `-cp` argument. It is used to add additional files to the classpath like jar files. I thought it would not make any difference when I use it all the time even if I do not specify any other files. Now I use it only if I really need it and it solved my problem. All expected files are there.

Though I am not sure why this does not compile all files.